# Parse JSON into data structure

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, computer-science

```
{
  "nose": {
    "color": 1
  },
  "wing": {
    "span": 24.0,
    "weight": 3.2,
    "flex": 0.93,
    "flaps": false
  },
  "tail": {},
  "cabin": {},
  "physics": {
    "cruise_control": false
  },
  "turbines": {
    "speed": 1.0
  },
  "gear": {
    "speed": 82.1,
    "rpm": 5200
  }
}
```

I am trying to parse the JSON above into a Data Structure. I was using Gson initially but most of the solutions recommended creating a class structure that mirrored the structure of my Gson and use fromJson(String, Class) but I don't want to do this cause the structure of the JSON might change and I don't want to have to format my classes every time.

Comment: Gson can parse to a JsonObject. `new JSONObject(jsonStr);`

Comment: are you willing to use Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a JSON string to a Gson `JsonElement` like this:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonObj = parser.parse(str);
```

According to the [Gson javadoc](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/index.html?com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) the resulting `JsonElement` can be

> a `JsonObject`, a `JsonArray`, a `JsonPrimitive` or a `JsonNull`